# Search results in Sphinx do not show text snippets with the searched word

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have installed a Sphinx system using the Read the Doc theme from scratch, with no additional configuration. Search box works well but the search results just show the pages that contain the word that I am searching for, but they don't show a snippet of the actual word in the context of the search.

This is working well in the Readthedoc site, this is for example the result of searching the word "number". The search page shows the pages that contain the "number" word and also a short snippet of the actual text with the "number" word highlighted in yellow

https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/search.html?q=number

[image: Example where the context is shown]

When I do a search in my system, these extra paragraphs with the highlighted text do not appear:

[image: Context not showing, just a link to the pages]

Should I add a specific configuration parameter to my conf.py file?

Any help is more than appreciated!

Comment: I can reproduce this with Chrome, but not with Firefox, when accessing the documentation from the file system (on Windows 10).

Comment: I can reproduce it with Firefox and Safari as well (Mac OS Big Sur 11.3.2), the snippets are not shown. Just in case it helps, I'm accessing the files from the file system in my local computer (there is no local HTTP server running), but it also happens when I upload the HTMLs to a web server

Comment: My bad... I have just noticed that it works well if there is a HTTP server providing the files instead of opening them from right the filesystem.

Comment: I think we can close this issue, I have just raised a but in the Sphinx-doc Github tracker: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9156